# How to add open files tab on distraction free mode

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

New (since 4.5?) distraction free mode is sweet. But can you add open files tab on distraction free mode?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Choose from menu:

**Window/Editor Tabs/Tabs Placement/**

Comment: Not correct in the latest version anymore, below @TuralAsgar's answer is the correct one now

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version it is under main **menu**

**Window/Editor Tabs/Configure Editor Tabs/**

[image]